# How to create immutable Doubly LinkedList in Scala?

Tags: scala, doubly-linked-list

Can someone help me to create immutable doubly linked list in Scala by showing one of the method implementation? Also, can you provide me one of example of it by let's implementing prepend(element:Int): DoublyLinkedList[Int] ?

Comment: You can not create an immutable doubly linked list without it being extremely inefficient because then any operation that returns a new list would need to copy the whole list, meaning that even the empty list would need to be replicated instead of shared. - Why do you need this? For homework? If so, are you at leas able to implement a single linked list?

Comment: When you create a new element you can pass it the reference to the previous element and make it immutable. But only after creating this element you have a reference that you could pass to the previous element so that it would store it as "next". You also cannot have one `Nil` element because it cannot point back to 2 previous elements from 2 different lists. As a matter of the fact you cannot reuse any element of the list when creating a new one. So you would have to reallocate whole list on every operation, making it basically an ineffective immutable array without O(1) index access.

Comment: Look up the search terms "Credit Card Transform" and "Tying the Knot". These are the two tricks you need.

Comment: [OMG!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH058GjFVpU)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to write an immutable doubly linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467669/is-it-possible-to-write-an-immutable-doubly-linked-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call By Name & lazy val (Call by need) makes it possible to have immutable doubly linked list.

Answer (score 2):

*Complementing the already linked video with a link to a text version and includinging important quotes:*

This is described at [Immutable Doubly Linked Lists in Scala with Call-By-Name and Lazy Values](https://blog.rockthejvm.com/immutable-doubly-linked-list-scala/)

> A doubly-linked list doesn’t offer too much benefit in Scala, quite the contrary.

> So this data structure is pretty useless from a practical standpoint, which is why ... there is no doubly-linked list in the Scala standard collection library

> All that said, a doubly-linked list is an excellent exercise on the mental model of immutable data structures.

> Think about it: this operation in Java would have been done in 3 steps:
>
> - new node
> - new node’s prev is 1
> - 1’s next is the new node
>
> If we can execute that new 1 ⇆ 2 in the same expression, we’ve made it; we can then recursively apply this operation on the rest of the list. Strangely enough, it’s possible.

```
class DLCons[+T](override val value: T, p: => DLList[T], n: => DLList[T]) extends DLList[T] {
  // ... other methods

  override def updatePrev[S >: T](newPrev: => DLList[S]) = {
    lazy val result: DLCons[S] = new DLCons(value, newPrev, n.updatePrev(result))
    result
  }
  
}
```

> Look at `updatePrev`: we’re creating a new node, whose next reference immediately points to a recursive call; the recursive call is on the current next node, which will update its own previous reference to the result we’re still in the process of defining! This forward reference is only possible in the presence of lazy values and the by-name arguments.